# Why is the site in read only mode?

Tags: discussion, read-only

I tried to access stackoverflow.com and I get the following message:

> This site is currently in read-only mode; we’ll return with full
>   functionality soon.

What's the reason?

Comment: Nothing on @StackStatus yet, we'll just have to be patient.

Comment: Nor on [stackstatus.net](https://www.stackstatus.net/).

Comment: Seriously, I get into work and you put SO into read only mode? How do you expect me to get any SO done if I have work to do?

Comment: Nice, just started following that Twitter account.

Comment: It's back now!!

Comment: Please folks, don't be so quick to post questions like this. Give the team a few minutes to either sort things out or update the various status sites.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158323/would-it-be-a-good-idea-to-have-a-read-only-version-of-stackoverflow-during-upgr/158327#158327

Comment: @ChrisF: Do you have any idea how many thousand lines of code gets written all across the world in a single minute? You grossly underestimate the magnitude of effect that "a few minutes" of Stack Overflow downtime could possibly have on the global economy.

Comment: exact duplicate of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208789/why-is-the-site-in-read-only-mode

Comment: **RELATED:** [Read-only mode status message, Request to add links to official status pages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231126/read-only-mode-status-message-request-to-add-links-to-official-status-pages)